# packaging my files in Illustrator CS6 is gone

Tags: adobe-illustrator, packages

suddenly I can find Packaging option under my file menu in Illustrator CS6!!!

[image: file menu in CS6 don't show package option]

Does anyone know how to get it back?? I did clean my cache and restart pc even i deleted my profile and create new one, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [Adobe's website](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/package-files.html) says that the Package feature should be available in CS6, I don't see it in mine either. I do have the option in Illustrator CC though. My CS6 is v16.0.3. [Elsewhere](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/30657/15321) on the interwebs, many are saying that it is a CC only feature.

From [this forum](http://macgroup.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/171604334/m/2987093036):

> I called Adobe and this is what they said, because I do not have the
>   Creative Cloud Subscription, it does not exist on my version of CS6.

Comment: this is crazy, how could a software enable embedding and don't allow collecting your external links in one package!! dose any plugins or scripts do the job?